# idiomatic error and value order using Multiple Return Values in go

Tags: go

When creating a `func` that returns both an error and a result, which order should they be in?  I've seen examples of both, and not sure where to look to confirm the idiomatic style.

should it be:

```
// a
func funcName(n int) (error, int) {}

// or b
func funcName(n int) (int, error) {}
```

Comment: If you look [here](https://gobyexample.com/errors), you will see `By convention, errors are the last return value and have type error, a built-in interface.`.

Comment: example `b` is correct as mentioned in golang documentation.

Comment: "and not sure where to look" then look at the stdlib.

Comment: "I've seen examples of both" - where have you seen an example of form A? Certainly not anywhere in the standard library.

Comment: no, you're right, not in the standard lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Gavin above in the comments :

> If you look [here](https://gobyexample.com/errors), you will see By convention, errors are the last return value and have type error, a built-in interface.

As can be seen in the standard lib.